# I need to return something from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to create more threads so one of my friends gave me some code for an "ThreadBuilder" but i can't return from a thread. I need now some help to do this. Some piece of code would also be great.

I have tried tried it with an one element final array and with Atomic Reference but it didnt work as expected.

```
package net.test;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class ThreadBuilder {

    private static String API_QUEUE = "API QUEUE";
    private static int threads = 0;

    private static final ExecutorService queue;

    static {
        ThreadFactory threadBuilder = r -> {
            Thread thread = new Thread(r, ThreadBuilder.API_QUEUE + ++ThreadBuilder.threads);
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            return thread;
        };
        queue = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(threadBuilder);
    }

    public static void run(Runnable runnable) {
        queue.execute(runnable);
    }

    public static ExecutorService getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use a `Callable<T>` instead of `Runnable`.

Comment: could you give me a code snippet?

Comment: and return the `Future` from `run`.

Comment: As Kayman sir suggested to use Callable or you can pass an object in the constructor and you can use in the later after thread completes.

Comment: i havent worked with callables yet. Can anybody help me implement this into my code?

Comment: @dotMatthew a `Callable` is effectively just a `Runnable` that returns a value: `Callable<String> aCallable = () -> "hello world"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Callable`, and return the result of the `queue.submit`:

```
public static <T> Future<T> run(Callable<T> callable) {
    return queue.submit(callable);
}
```

When the `Future` has completed, you can get the result using `Future.get`.

---

I would also point out that your `ThreadBuilder` class is worse than just using an `ExecutorService` directly. For example, you can't shut your executor down, await termination etc. Plus, you are introducing a static binding to that class, which makes things harder to isolate, test etc.

It would be better simply to have a static factory method to create the `ExecutorService`, and then interact with the `ExecutorService` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I can think of is creating a class to hold the result of the computation or whatever you are performing on a different thread, then pass an instance of that class as a parameter to the `Runnable` itself (kind of like a has-a relation). Then inside the `run()` method of the `Runnable`, when the result is obtained, then pass the result on to the result storing object.

Basically, it's the [Observer Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

This is a actually a bad solution as you have to keep checking whether the result storing object has been updated or not and this is fundamentally bad for design. 
The only reason why I am suggesting this answer is that you do not know about `Callable` and I suggest you learn and then refer to [@AndyTurner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58537636/6601614)